# jQuery script failing on live but working on staging. Cannot identify why

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have the following page deployed on both live and staging:

https://www.professionalformulas.com/products/

https://www.staging4.professionalformulas.com/products/

When clicking any product, a "Get Access" popup should open.  This works on staging, but on live a console error is reported:

TypeError: b.style is undefined in theme.min.js:17:5880

I've spent a long time comparing plugin versions, PHP version, the way/order the scripts are loaded et cetera and I cannot see why the error is occurring on live and not on staging.

I've even compared the raw source code using diffchecker and confirmed that the source code is the same between both versions. Everything is the same from what I can see.

I'd like to get some insight on what I could be missing.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just wanted to add that I've confirmed all caching is disabled. Site is hosted with Siteground.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cssText' of undefined
    at theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:17
    at Function.<anonymous> (theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:17)
    at p.check (theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:18)
    at new p (theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:18)
    at a._gsDefine (theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:18)
    at Array.<anonymous> (theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:17)
    at theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:19
    at theme.min.js?ver=4.6.0:19`

Comment: in theme.min.js >> (b.style.cssText="top:1px;opacity:.55;",/^0.55/.test(b.style.opacity)) 
strange..

Comment: I can see the undefined errors occur on live, however the exact same script (byte for byte) on the staging server works perfectly with no undefined errors. I cannot find any environmental differences and seeing as staging is a carbon copy of the production site, I cannot understand whats going on. Been banging my head against the wall with this issue for a couple days now!

Comment: Making the debugger pause on thrown exceptions, the `b` in question has an `outerHTML` value of `<a></a>`.

Comment: @CristiC777 yeah I do see that b.style on that line has a value so it makes no sense to me why its reading as undefined.